# How do I check the type of a widget programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, widget

I want to check the type of a widget programmatically.

```
View v = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
```

How do I check if `v` is a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
View v = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);

if(v instanceof RelativeLayout) {
    // RelativeLayout
} else if (v instanceof LinearLayout){
    // LinearLayout
}
```

Although you probably should use `findViewById()` to find the `Widget` you want.

```
View v = tabHost.getTabWidget().findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayoutView);
```